# Is there any way to lookup friendship in Tweepy via API v2?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Is there any way to use similiar method but with API v2 (Client class)?

I used this method
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.lookup_friendships

```
API.lookup_friendships()
```

But now I need to migrate to API v2

Comment: HI AliAidan When I try and use this endpoint: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-lookup I get {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource",
      "code": 37
    }
  ]
} I can use GET users/lookup without any problem? Do you know why I am getting access issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent endpoint in Twitter API v2 yet.
You can refer to the [Twitter API endpoint map](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/migrate/twitter-api-endpoint-map) in the Twitter API documentation.
It says "[COMING SOON]" for [GET friendships/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-lookup), the Twitter API endpoint `API.lookup_friendships` uses,.